# Debian 9 not booting to GUI

Tags: debian, boot, system-installation

I've just installed Debian 9 into an old Toshiba notebook and everything went fine during the installation:

> **Installation complete**
>   Installation is complete, so it is time to boot into your new system. Make sure to remove the installation media, so that you boot into the new system rather than restarting the installation.

However, after restarting, the system showed several error messages and then stopped on a dark screen (it is still possible to switch to consoles via alt-ctrl-f2~f6):

```
[drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
[drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* pipe B underrun
[drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
[drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
```

Any ideas?

---

**Notebook Specifications**
[Toshiba Satellite 1135-S1553](https://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=434998)

- Intel® Celeron® 4 processor at 2.20GHz
- Intel 852GM Chipset
- 1Gb RAM
- 32MB internal Integrated Intel® 852GM video memory

**Debian Version**

- [Small CDs](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst#smallcd)
- [debian-9.4.0-i386-netinst.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/i386/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-i386-netinst.iso)
- DVD burnt via Win7

**Software selection**
(X) Debian desktop environment
(  ) ... GNOME
(  ) ... Xfce
(  ) ... KDE
(  ) ... Cinnamon
(  ) ... MATE
(  ) ... LXDE
(  ) web server
(X) print server
(  ) SSH server
(X) standard system utilities

**outputs and log files excerpts**
*/var/log/installer# grep EE Xorg.0.log*

```
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown
[8.534] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[8.535] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[8.538] (EE) open /dev/dri/card 0: No such file or directory
[8.538] (EE) open /dev/dri/card 0: No such file or directory
[8.538] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section
```

*/var/log/installer/syslog*

```
pci 0000:02:04.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
pci_bud 0000:03:busn_res: can not insert [bus 03-02] under [bus 02] conflicts with (null) [bus 02])
gnome-shell [548]: Failed to allocate texture: Failed to create texture 2d due to size/format constraints
```

*apt install xserver-xorg-video-{vesa,intel}*

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20161206-1)
xserver-xorg-video-vesa is already the newest version (1:2.3.4-1+b2).
xserver-xorg-video-vesa set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you installed a window manager, gnome, KDE or other?

Comment: During the installation, I've left the *Software Selection* with its default items checked, ie: Debian desktop environment, print server and standard system utilities.

Comment: How much RAM have you got?

Comment: If you log in at the prompt and run `startx` what happens?  Does `service status gdm` report anything?  Does `service gdm restart` do anything for you?  Whoops.. nm. Just read you aren't even getting a login prompt.

Comment: @ivanivan `startx` from console basically enters in a similar 'freezed' dark screen, blinks sometimes and returns to the console. The output I've just added to the original post.

Comment: @ivanivan console input => `service status gdm` | console output => `status: unrecognized service`

Comment: @ivanivan console input => `service gdm restart` | opens a similar 'freezed' dark screen. `ctrl-alt-f2` showed no output for this command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no desktop environment (DE) was individually selected during the installation, GNOME was the default choice. However, GNOME seems to be too heavy for the available system. Therefore, changing the DE to some other lighter solved the issue:

*install a light DE (ex: mate, xfce or lxde)*

```
apt install tasksel aptitude
tasksel
```

*select and start the new DE*

```
update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
exec startx
```

Of course the script above is just an workaround, the ideal would be reinstalling Debian and selecting only this DE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link below to download the `debian-desktop-environment-manager-cli`.

[Github link for debian-desktop-environment-manager-cli](https://github.com/david-kariuki/debian-desktop-environment-manager-cli.sh)

It will help you install, debug and uninstall desktop environments of your choice depending on your computers' resources.